# Create javascript reference file of JSON object for intellisense

Tags: javascript, c#, json, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I am using C# to create a rather complicated data object that contains a couple of lists of objects that is then serialized and sent to the client.  I like this approach a lot because I am using the same object definition in both my client and server side code.

I'd like to create some sort of reference file for Visual Studio 2012 so that intellisense can help me out, typos in my javascript code seem to be my biggest problem in debugging.

Does anybody have any tips for doing this?  I understand that as I add new properties to the C# class I will need to refresh this reference file.

Comment: there could be several answers to this depending on the nature of the problem. you might just need to stop typing so many typos, or there may be a smart programmatic way to parse the json and avoid typos altogether. providing more information or code samples would help this question a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `T4 template` to generate javascipt viewmodel file from your C# class.

Take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578827/Generate-Knockout-Viewmodels-using-T-templates).

Also some [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437654/t4-c-sharp-class-to-knockout-view-model-in-typescript) [information](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/32c15a80-1c54-4e96-a83f-7cd57573a5d2) [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).